# Links to Manufacturers\Categories\Products not rendering

Tags: nopcommerce

I am in the middle of determining if nopCommerce is suitable for our requirements.  I am a "nop Newbie" and learning as I go.

I have loaded manufacturers, categories and products.  I have installed the quick menu plugin from nop4u with both categories and manufacturers to show on menu.  However when I load the home page nearly all links go nowhere. If I view the page source the links to all sub categories all look like this:

```
<a>Jigsaws</a>
```

Main parent categories look correct:

```
<a href="/puzzles">Puzzles</a>
```

I click on "Puzzles" the Puzzles category is loaded.  At the top of the page is icons for all the sub categories of Puzzles (I don't want these) and below that are products within the Puzzles category and sub categories of Puzzles.  However I am seeing the same problem if I try to navigate to a product details page. It seems to only render links correctly for top level categories

I disabled the quick menu but the problem persists.

Would anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using any other plugin and did any customization? I've tried to configure quick menu plugin and it's working correctly. Could you please explain with some screen?

Comment: I found the problem in the end.  It was nothing to do with the menu,  I created my own dataloader and missed the entry in UrlRecord. (Duh!)  As soon as I worked out how to mimic the slug value I corrected this it all worked perfectly.

Comment: Okay, glad to hear your issue has been resolved !! it would be great if you add upper comment as an answer, It may helps to other in future!!